# When to use {!v.variableName} and {!variableName}?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So I was learning Lightning and I was practicing by watching some tutorial from YouTube and I got confused with the usage of {!v.variableName} and {!variableName}.

I wrote this and the output was : redgreenorangeyellowpurple ; which is fine as expected. See that I have used {!singleColour} inside the iteration loop.

```
<aura:component >   
<aura:attribute name="coloursList" type="list" default="['red','green','orange','yellow','purple']"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.coloursList}" var="singleColour">
    {!singleColour}
</aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Now when I change the same {!singleColour} to {!v.singleColour} in the same code as above, I get no result. I am not able to understand when to put "v." before and when not. Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance,
Ali

Comment: i'd suggest you take a look at [Trailheads: Attributes and Expressions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_attributes_expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v` is a *[Value Provider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm)*. Specifically, `v` provides values that are stored in an `aura:attribute`. So, if you need to reference a value stored in an `aura:attribute`, use `v`. If you need to access a value referenced by `var` (from `aura:iteration`), you do not use  `v`.

In addition, there's a second Value Provider you need to know about, `c`. This Value Provider can return a reference to a client- or server-side method. You use it to call methods from the server, as well as to call methods in the *myComponent*Controller.js file. There are other Value Providers as well; please check the documentation above to learn more about those.

Comment: ohhh...okay..got it...thanks for the clarification!!!